# servlert : The requested resource is not available

Tags: servlets

Whenever I entered URL for opening a jsp page ..i am getting "The requested resource (/page/form.jsp) is not available." error Page and in my file structure 
WebContent->WEB-INF ->page->form.jsp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stuff in `WEB-INF` is not directly made accessible.

`/page/form.jsp` would map to `WebContent/page/form.jsp` (outside of `WEB-INF`).

Comment: thanks its solved but now i am getting error Page when I click on form.jsp , error is "org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler generateClass   SEVERE: Javac exception 
Error starting modern compiler" .Please help

Comment: It seems an error we can't solve without viewing the code. If you still have that problem it's better to open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is jsp file shouldn’t be present inside WEB-INF folder move it under web content
This will solve your issue